# log(1+exp(X)) in Tensorflow (avoiding under and over flows)

Tags: tensorflow, nan, integer-overflow, exp

I was debugging my program and I've realized that I my loss outputted NaN. These NaN values comes from the fact that I'm computing `tf.log(1 + tf.exp(X))`

where X is a 2d tensor. Indeed, When a value of X is large enough then tf.exp() returns +Inf and so `tf.log(1 + exp(X))` will return `+Inf`. I was wondering if there exists a neat trick to avoid underflows and overflows in this case.

I have tried:

```py
def log1exp(x):
    maxi = tf.reduce_max(x)
    return maxi + tf.log(tf.exp(x - maxi) + tf.exp(-maxi))
```

but it doesn't handle underflows in this case...

Also I've glanced at `tf.reduce_logsumexp` but it necessarily reduce the tensor along an axis... while I want to keep the same shape!

Finally I know that `tf.log(1 + exp(X))` is almost equal to `X` for large values of X but I think that designing a function that will output `X` when `X > threshold` and log(1+exp(X)) otherwise is not very neat.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is already implemented in tensorflow under the name [`tf.math.softplus`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/softplus), and takes care of overflows and underflows.

Comment: `tf.nn.softplus` does *not* take care of overflows, as one can easily verify by passing it a large input.

Comment: @sebastian_k `tf.math.softplus(np.finfo(np.float32).max)` does not overflow over here, and that is pretty much the biggest input I can think of.

Comment: thanks for testing that – very strange, as I regularly have to work around `tf.nn.softplus` spitting out `nan` when the inputs get too large. I wonder if there's something else to it?

Comment: @sebastian_k Might indeed be worth its own question here on SO.

Comment: I eat my words, you're right: `core/kernels/softplus_op.h` clearly branches on the input value. I wonder if my problems are caused in the gradient calculation ... I'll have to dig into that! :)

Comment: ```with tf.Session() as sess:```

Comment: ```tf.math.softplus(tf.math.exp(10.0*10)).eval()```

Comment: It returns ```Inf```

Comment: @DachuanZhao That's because `exp(10.0*10)` lies outside `float32` range.